# Can not use weka.core modules after successfull installation of python-weka-wrapper "No module named 'weka.core'"

Tags: python-3.x, weka, ubuntu-18.04

I've installed python-weka-wrapper with its all dependencies like the following command shows:

```
sudo -H pip3 install python-weka-wrapper3
Requirement already satisfied: python-weka-wrapper3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/python_weka_wrapper3-0.1.7-py3.6.egg
Requirement already satisfied: javabridge>=1.0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from python-weka-wrapper3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy-1.17.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg (from python-weka-wrapper3)
```

but, when I try to import ***weka.core.converters*** I get the followin error :
**`No module named 'weka.core'.`**
And moreover, I can find all of these modules in the directory

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/python_weka_wrapper3-0.1.7-py3.6.egg/weka
```

I can lso import **`weka.core.converters`** with python2.7, ,but I really need to use it with python3.

My machine infos:
OS: Ubuntu 18.0.4

python : 3.6.8 & 2.7.15

Comment: Can you run the following command: `python3 -c "import weka.core.jvm as jvm; jvm.start(); jvm.stop();"`

Comment: It throws the same error!

Comment: Hmm... I had no problems with globally installed javabridge/pww for both, Python 27 and Python 3. How about removing the global installations of javabridge and python-weka-wrapper for both, Python 2.7 and Python 3 and then installing virtual environments via the virtualenv tool: `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 pww27` and `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 pww36`. Then you can install pww inside them with `pww27/bin/pip install numpy javabridge python-weka-wrapper` and `pww36/bin/pip install numpy javabridge python-weka-wrapper3`. Then run previous test command from within virtual envs.

Comment: Well, after some search i used anaconda platform, I've created 2 environments as you said..I think I had two problems: **1- I should had oracle jdk instead of open jdk(solved)**. **2- python-weka-wrapper could not be installed without root access "sudo ip install ..",  and that's why python can not see it(not solved yet).**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong in your install, but here are the steps that I performed to get **python-weka-wrapper** installed for [Python 2.7](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper) and [3.6](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3), on a freshly installed (and fully up-to-date) Ubuntu 18.04.1:

First, ensure to have `pip` installed and you can compile source code:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python3-pip virtualenv build-essential
```

Though [Oracle JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) is recommended, you can get it to work with OpenJDK as well, just make sure to install the sources as well:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-source openjdk-8-jdk
```

I'm not a big fan of [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/), as I find it overkill, especially since `virtualenv` does things in a much leaner, cleaner and faster way. The instructions below create directories (`pww27` and `pww36` in your current directory), which you can simply delete, if you no longer require these virtual environments.
But, I've also listed instructions on how to use Anaconda further below.

Each of the virtual environments will run a test command: import the `jvm` module, start and stop the JVM, using `python -c "..."`, to check whether the environment is working. This command will generate output similar to the following (paths will be different, of course):

```
DEBUG:weka.core.jvm:Adding bundled jars
DEBUG:weka.core.jvm:Classpath=['/home/fracpete/pww36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/javabridge/jars/rhino-1.7R4.jar', '/home/fracpete/pww36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/javabridge/jars/runnablequeue.jar', '/home/fracpete/pww36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/javabridge/jars/cpython.jar', '/home/fracpete/pww36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/weka/lib/python-weka-wrapper.jar', '/home/fracpete/pww36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/weka/lib/weka.jar']
DEBUG:weka.core.jvm:MaxHeapSize=default
DEBUG:weka.core.jvm:Package support disabled
```

OK, let's create the virtual environments and test them:

**1. virtual environment for Python 2.7 (virtualenv):**

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 pww27
pww27/bin/pip install numpy
pww27/bin/pip install javabridge
pww27/bin/pip install python-weka-wrapper
pww27/bin/python -c "import weka.core.jvm as jvm; jvm.start(); jvm.stop()"
```

**2. virtual environment for Python 3.6 (virtualenv):**

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 pww36
pww36/bin/pip install numpy
pww36/bin/pip install javabridge
pww36/bin/pip install python-weka-wrapper3
pww36/bin/python -c "import weka.core.jvm as jvm; jvm.start(); jvm.stop()"
```

**3. virtual environment for Python 2.7 (anaconda3-2019.07):**

```
conda create -n pww27 python=2.7
conda activate pww27
pip install numpy
pip install javabridge
pip install python-weka-wrapper
python -c "import weka.core.jvm as jvm; jvm.start(); jvm.stop()"
conda deactivate
```

**4. virtual environment for Python 3.6 (anaconda3-2019.07):**

```
conda create -n pww36 python=3.6
conda activate pww36
pip install numpy
pip install javabridge
pip install python-weka-wrapper
python -c "import weka.core.jvm as jvm; jvm.start(); jvm.stop()"
conda deactivate
```

Comment: Thanks for Your help, I tried using anaconda and virtualenv and everything was installed correctly,  but I could not import any pip installed package.. So I just cloned javabridge and python-weka-wrapper repos from github and build then installed them and that worked!!